# Networked clients in java

Tags: java, networking

I am making an application that shall allow users to see what someone else on the network is editing.The libraries i have googled *so far* have client to server and not client to client.What library in java can i use instead of writing one from scratch?.

Comment: This involves a bit more research into asynchronous communication (a-la AJAX) and how it can apply to your application.  I would *strongly* encourage more research first, then present SO with a specific question about implementation.

Comment: Thanks Makoto, i shall do more research and come back soon.

Comment: The question is tagged as Java, so I supposed this is no web application, but I might be wrong. What kind of application are you working on? We may be able to point you to the right resource.

Comment: Its a desktop application,but let me not bother you with all the hypothesis.I shall come back when i have something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way TCP and UDP work (I guess you want to use these protocols and create your own on top of them) is that a host have to contacts another to exchange information. At the end, there is always programs listening (probably what you refer as a *server*) and programs initiating connections (*client*).

Note that both programs can run on each node, as it is usually the case in peer to peer applications (they may even run in the same executable).

Based on the application you are  describing in your question, a simple approach could be that each node runs a server application listening for notification of people starting or stopping editing, while the client (node initiating connections) notify all interested *servers* when a user starts editing. In order to do that, clients will have to keep a list of all potential writers on the network. To create and maintain this list of nodes accross a LAN, the best approach would be to implement a discovery protocol like [Zeroconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf).